# Java/Slf4J: Custom logging for a single class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I have a Spring Boot app with an `application.yml` like follows:

```
logging:
       level:
             com.mycompany.TestClass: OFF
```

With this, I can control whether the class outputs any logs or not. What I would like to do is that for this specific class, format the messages of exceptions without the stack trace (without affecting any non-exception loggings). For example, if the some method the of the class throws an exception and I am logging the exception as follows:

```
try {
  //throw index of bounds exception
} catch(Exception e){
  log.error("Error occurred: " + e)
}
```

I want only below part(without stack trace):

```
Error occurred: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

Is this at all possible ?

**EDIT**
I am trying to target the logging of a JAR file - I don't have access to modify the code...

Answer (score 2):

You have to use exception depth in logback.xml if you are using. There is a facility in logback along with slf4j where you can mention the length of exception stacktrace. I provide below the snippet.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <!-- %rEx... prints exception causes in REVERSE order: http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/09/logging-exceptions-root-cause-first.html -->
            <pattern>
                <![CDATA[%-19(%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%.8thread]) %-5level   %-128(%-32(%replace(%logger{1}){'^org\.wrml.*\.',''}) - %msg) %n%rEx]]></pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

You have to use proper layout.

Refer below the links for more understanding.

https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/09/logging-exceptions-root-cause-first.html

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#rootException

If you want to configure with application.yml, you can refer below the link.

https://springframework.guru/using-yaml-in-spring-boot-to-configure-logback/

Comment: anyway to configure with the `application.yml` or `application.properties` file ?

Comment: @GdgamesGamers, I have updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @GdgamesGamers, if you find it helpful, could you please upvote it and mark as answered ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `e.getMessage()` instead of only passed an `e` variable. So your code will looks like this :

```
try {
  //throw index of bounds exception
} catch(Exception e){
  log.error("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
}
```